# Импорт и функциональность модулей в es2015

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel, модули

Приветствую!

Столкнулся с проблемой или особенностью(я еще не понял), что при перезде проекта с gulp & require на webpack(webpack3.4 & babel-loader). немного поменялся импорт модулей и их вызов.

Ранее я определял модули так:

```
define(function(){
  var obj={};
  obj.foo = function(){
   console.log("requireJS")
  };
  return obj;
});
```

и вызывал так:

```
define([
    "require",
    "lib/module"
], function(
  require,
  module){
    module.foo();
});
```

В новом же проекте с webpack все происходит несколько иначе.

Определяю модуль примерно так:

```
export default function() {
  var obj = {};
  obj.foo = ()=>{
    console.log("Hello Friends!")
  };
  return obj;
}
```

И импорт с вызовом происходит так:

```
import _module from "modules/module";

let module = _module();

module.foo();
```

В принципе жить можно, **но есть ли способ организовать код таким образом, что бы свеже импортированный модуль был уже готов к работе?** пример:

```
import module from "modules/module";

module.foo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы сделать так как я хочу -- можно модуль организовать таким образом:

```
"use strict";
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
function test(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.a = 123;
    obj.b = "fff";
    obj.foo = ()=>{
        console.log("Hello Friends!");
    };
    return obj;
}

export default test();
```

Или так:

```
export default {
  foo:{console.log("Hello Friends!")},
  a:123,
  b:"fff"
};
```

И вызвать следующим образом:

```
import module from "modules/module";
test.foo();
```